# Does Spring Session require the use of Spring Security?

Tags: spring, session, session-cookies

Does spring session internally require the use of spring security?

Right now, we have an existing application which uses HTTP session from servlet container (e.g. WebLogic). Due to some issues on session replication and for future plans to use another servlet container, we decided to look for existing framework that would make the HTTP session container independent.

The team decided to look at Spring Session in combination with Hazelcast as described in official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-hazelcast). We use spring session version 1.3.5.RELEASE.

For hazelcast configuration, we use this session configuration.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
<bean id="hazelcastInstance" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="xxx.xxx.xxx.cache.CustomHazelcastProvider.getInstance"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="xxx.xxx.xxx.util.CustomHttpSessionListener"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
    <property name="cookieName" value="JSESSIONID"/>
    <property name="cookiePath" value="/"/>
    <property name="domainNamePattern" value="^.+?\.(\w+\.[a-z]+)$"/>
</bean>
```

In web.xml, we put this filter chain.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CustomServletRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>xxx.xxx.xxx.servlet.filter.CustomServletRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomServletRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And added spring configuration below in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In the same web.xml, we use form-based authentication.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

In addition, we are using the default cookie based HTTP strategy.

After deploying the said changes in weblogic, we are able to get a successful login. Able to check the session ID coming from spring session. However, the next hop or succeeding REST calls, it always returns HTTP 302. It gets redirected to login page.

Does spring session require the use of spring security? Is there some configuration that we need to add to resolve this issue?

Will appreciate any help or suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: In theory no it doesn't. However I suspect that the security check as configured by JEE are executed before the filter chain is being called. Which means Spring Session has no change to replace or obtain the HTTP session.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the quick response. I tried to comment out the configuration related to DefaultCookieSerializer, and able to proceed and have HTTP 200 results in the succeeding REST callls. However, the request cookie contains 2 values: SESSION and JSESSIONID. Although the HTTP session used inside the application is spring session, but I think it works because the JSESSIONID is still passed. Not sure if extra configuration will be done on the container side.

Comment: @M.Deinum, is there a way to disable the security check in the servlet container side and let the security be handled by the application? or how can we make sure that spring session be triggered first before anything else? Right now, **springSessionRepositoryFilter** is already the first entry in my filter chain and in my web.xml. Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: You would need to check with Tomcat for that. AFAIK the constraints are even applied before the filter chain had a chance to kick in. So it doesn't matter where your filter is in the chain, it hasn't had a chance to do anything yet.